# displaying html5 video in ios without play button overlay

Tags: ios, html, video

I am trying to display an image that when clicked will open up a video player in html 5, but I don't want the little semi-transparent play button to appear over it.  Is there any way to specify in the  tag not to put that icon over the poster image and just display the poster image as is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** This is no longer the best method - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36401013/1813169) answer below for an actual solution.

---

As far as I'm aware, the play button overlay is added by the rendering engine in mobile Safari, so no there is no way to hide it.  However, you may be able to spoof it using ajax to load the video when a static image is clicked.  For example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="videoContainer">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#videoContainer {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/60x40.png);
  height: 40px;
  width: 60px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#videoContainer").click(function() {
  $(this).css('background', 'none').parent().html("<video id=\"video\" width=\"60\" height=\"40\">\n" +
    "<source src=\"video.mp4\" type=\"video/mp4\">\n" +
    "<source src=\"video.ogg\" type=\"video/ogg\">\n" +
    "</video>");
  $("#video").get(0).play();
});
```

Comment: Alas because of iOS restrictions that only kind of sort of works, you cannot auto-play the movie.  However it does work for what I need it to.

Answer (score 12):

You can hide the overlay **play** button on the iPhone with just some CSS:

```css
video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: @bfred.it I have added this [html appendFormat:@"video { webkit-media-controls: none}"];
not working for me.

Comment: @Jitendra where did you put that, in `style` tags?

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This hides ALL the controls, including that's that come up with the `controls` attribute in Chrome and Safari